# Get Hebrew calendar date with JS

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I am trying to get the Hebrew calendar date so I can base a function off of the current Hebrew date.
Something like this

```
if (monthName == "Tishrei") {
    $('.Tishrei').css('display', 'block')
```

so I can control what shows up on my webpage based on what today's date is.

I tried to get the number of the month like this

```
var monthNumber = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'narrow' }).format(new Date());
```

which correctly returns the number of the month but when I tried to use it in a switch statement it didn't work, it just returned the default. Here is my switch statement:

```
switch (monthNumber) {
      case 1:
        monthName = "Tishrei"
        break;
```

I also thought about using the names of the months -

```
var monthNumber = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'narrow' }).format(new Date());
```

but the spelling of Hebrew words written in English varies and I don't know which spelling is used in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: So ... just saying ... `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'narrow' }).format(new Date())` returns `3`.

Comment: To get the full month name, use `month: 'long'`, or abbreviated is `month: 'short'`. Currently, `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'long' }).format(new Date())` returns "Kislev".

Comment: PS. You can also use `new Date().toLocaleString('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'long' })`, which is a little less code to type. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after console logging -  `typeof(monthNumber)` it shows us that it is a string.

You need to change the `monthNumber` to a number.

Here is how you can do that:

```
var monthNumber = Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', { month: 'narrow' }).format(new Date()))

switch (monthNumber) {
  case 1:
    monthName = "Tishrei"
  case 2:
    monthName = "Cheshvan"
  case 3:
    monthName = "Kislev"
  break
}

console.log(monthName)
```

Answer (score 3):

> …but the spelling of Hebrew words written in English varies and I don't know which spelling is used in this case.

The Intl object should use data from the CLDR project, so the English names should be the same across all browsers.

The following function gets the Hebrew month names using *Intl.DateTimeFormat*. Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera return an identical list. Maybe Edge is different.

```js
function getHebrewMonthNames() {
  let d = new Date(2022,0);
  let months = {};
  let fNum = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'numeric'});
  let fName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'long'});
  for (let i=1; i<366; i++) {
    d.setDate(i);
    if (!months[fNum.format(d)]) {
      months[fNum.format(d)] = fName.format(d);
    }
  }
  return months;
}

console.log(getHebrewMonthNames());
/* {
  "1": "Tishri",
  "2": "Heshvan",
  "3": "Kislev",
  "4": "Tevet",
  "5": "Shevat",
  "6": "Adar",
  "7": "Adar II",
  "8": "Nisan",
  "9": "Iyar",
  "10": "Sivan",
  "11": "Tamuz",
  "12": "Av",
  "13": "Elul"
} */
```

A simple function to get the current month name based on a list is:

```js
function getHebrewMonthName(d = new Date()) {
  return [,"Tishri", "Heshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet",
           "Shevat", "Adar", "Adar II", "Nisan", 
           "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tamuz", "Av", "Elul"]
         [d.toLocaleString('en-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'numeric'})];
}

console.log('Current Hebrew month from list: ' + 
  getHebrewMonthName()
);
console.log('Current Hebrew month from Intl: ' +
  new Date().toLocaleString('en-u-ca-hebrew', {month: 'long'})
);
```